# MySQL Query using SubQueries Added Together to Sequelize Format

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following MySQL query which uses subqueries and sums them together.

```
SELECT *,(SELECT count(`id`) FROM `Texts` WHERE `UserId` = 
`Users`.`id`) + (SELECT count(`id`) FROM `Calls` WHERE `UserId` = 
`Users`.`id`) as `totalTextsAndCalls` FROM `Users` WHERE `id` IN 
(1,2) ORDER BY `totalTextsAndCalls` DESC
```

This query works when I test manually right now and gives me the results I want.

**I'm not sure how you handle subqueries in Sequelize however**.  I've looked into the Sequelize literals but not sure if this is the only way to do this? I can't seem to get the literal to work either.  I will post my attempts at Sequelize writing this shortly if they are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @RishikeshDhokare, wasn't sure how to format that for some reason.

Comment: while formatting the text into code blocks it needs at least couple of spaces, thats what i added :)